# Setting unit scope in XE2

Tags: delphi, scope, delphi-xe2

Further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775578/please-explain-package-use), I had an error when trying to call `MessageDlg()`

`[DCC Error] MainForm.pas(54): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'mtError'`

So I pulled up help and found that `mtError` is declared in `Dialogs`.

I opened Project/Options/Unit scope names and added `Dialogs`.

And I still get the same error.

I can has halpz?

Comment: There's something strange about your project. If I use `File->New->VCL Forms Appiication`, create a new `FormCreate` event, and then type `MessageDlg('Test message', mtError, [mbOK], 0);`, it compiles fine without any warnings or errors using the default compiler options.

Comment: This was answered specifically in the second link I posted to your last question (the subtopic `Fully Qualified Names Must Include the Unit Scope Name`). :)

Comment: +2 Ken, I agree there is soemthing strange. I am now creating a new project from scratch & slowly adding things. I will report back, but you might want to post soem kind of answer whcih I coudl award...

Comment: +1 just for the reference to lolcats :) go get yourself a cheeseburger to help with the re-adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered in the second link I posted to your last question (the subtopic `Fully Qualified Names Must Include the Unit Scope Name`.

There's something strange about your project, though. If I create a new VCL project (`File->New->VCL Forms Application`), and then add the following code, it compiles fine with no changes to default compiler settings.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageDlg('Test message', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

Comment: +1 Thansk very, very much for your help Ken.  I can't remember if my project was inmported from D7; failing that it was based on an Indy demo & I think those are also D7.  In any case, starting from scratch & adding components and codes piece by piece has gotten it working

Answer (score 5):

Add `Vcl` instead of `Dialogs` in `Project->Options->Unit scope names`.

Comment: To elaborate in this, `Dialogs` is a unit that exists in the `Vcl` scope.  In the `Unit Scope Names` list, you specify scopes, not units. Then, to allow `mtError` to resolve, add `Dialogs` to your `uses` clause. If `Vcl` is not specified in the `Unit Scope Names` list, then the `uses` clause needs to specify `Vcl.Dialogs` instead.